# Function template isn't producing random numbers properly

Tags: c++, templates, random, vector

I have a function template that is supposed to take a vector and produce random numbers inside it. However, when I print entire vector, it's all zeros.

code:

```
const  int smallSize = 20;

// declare small vector
vector <int> smallVector(smallSize);

genRand(smallVector, smallSize);

// make copy of small vector 
vector<int> copySmallVector = smallVector;

// function template for generating random numbers
template<class T, class B>void genRand(T data, B size)
{
    for (B i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = (1 + rand() % size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you call `srand()` to seed the random engine anywhere?

Comment: I added, srand into my main, I continue to get random generation of all 0

Comment: Paul R's answer is correct, though calling `srand()` should be done once.

Comment: Consider `generate(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), rand);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are generating random numbers in a *copy* of your vector, and then throwing it away when the function returns.

Change:

```
template<class T, class B>void genRand(T data, B size)
```

to:

```
template<class T, class B>void genRand(T &data, B size)
                                       ^^^^^^^
```